# how to retrieve data from database without refreshing page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i having a drop down box, it have two client(ex:client a,client b),i have more then 2000 data in each client table ,when selecting client i want to retrieve all data from database and show it in front end with out refreshing,now i am refresh  `window.location` this refresh the page.can any one help me how to do that thanks

**Ajax**

```
<script>
$(function() {    document.ready
    $("#client").on("change", function() {
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        var clientid=$("#client").val();
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            data: {
                clientselect: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#display").html(data);
                window.location = '?action=clientnetworkpricelist&clientid='+clientid+'';
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Select Box

```
 <select name="client" id="client" style="margin:-24px 0 0 1px;background-color:#E8E8E8;width:104px;position: absolute;"> 
   <option value="">Select Client</option>
<?php

$sql=mysql_query("select * from client_list");

$clientid=$_GET['clientid'];



while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

{


    if(strlen($_GET['clientid'])>0 && $_GET['clientid']==$row['clientid']){
    print' <option id="client" name="client" value="'.$row['clientid'].'" selected>'.$row['clientid'].' </option>';}

    else{

            print' <option id="client" name="client" value="'.$row['clientid'].'" >'.$row['clientid'].' </option>';
    }

   }



   ?>


</select>
```

Comment: data appended to #display then why you reload?

Comment: can you please write down the code

Comment: where you posting url?

Comment: because i want to retrieve  data from database for the selected client  .i tried this what you said "$("#display").append(html);" and removed the window.location but its not displaying data from database for the selected client,can you write down code

Comment: ok i need that select box html,so post it that part too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41508/discussion-between-arokia-and-sridhar-r)

Comment: is this on same domain call?

Comment: @yes but it showing  SyntaxError: missing } after property list
 

url: http://xxxxxx + "?action=clientnetworkpricelist&cl

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    url: "your_web_address?action=clientnetworkpricelist&clientid="+clientid,
                    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#display").html(data);
                        $("#flash").hide();
                    },
                    error: function (request, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                    }
                });
```

change url to:

url: "http://www.yourpage.com/your_subpage?action=clientnetworkpricelist&clientid="+clientid

Comment: thanks for my reply can you please see my updated ajax code it shows error  ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
 

...//xxxxxxx.com+ "?action=clientnetworkpricelist&clientid='+clientid+'""

Comment: thanks but now its like this 
GET http://webpage.com/index.php?action=cli...celist&clientid=%27+clientid+%27&_=1384937544602 its not takeing the selected client id also its repeating twice

Comment: whats repeating twice? try alert(clientid); to see what do you have inside  clientid var

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, actually what you are doing, you change your url, so that is why you get refresh on each and every time when you change your drop down selection.

I have little bit change your selection code, i.e. I remove select keyword from if option section, secondly i have added a div after finishing of selection, as you should see in below.

**SELECTION CODE**

```
<select name="client" id="client" style="margin:-24px 0 0 1px;background-color:#E8E8E8;width:104px;position: absolute;"> 
<option value="">Select Client</option>
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from client_list");
$clientid=$_GET['clientid'];
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
if(strlen($_GET['clientid'])>0 && $_GET['clientid']==$row['clientid'])
{
print' <option id="client" name="client" value="'.$row['clientid'].'">'.$row['clientid'].' </option>';
}
else{
print' <option id="client" name="client" value="'.$row['clientid'].'">'.$row['clientid'].' </option>';
}
}
?>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now I have change your ajax code. which is given below. You need to create one more file yourfile.php, this file contain data which you want to display.

**AJAX CODE**

```
<script>
$(function() { document.ready
    $("#client").on("change", function() {
      var clientid=$("#client").val();
    $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"yourfile.php",
        data:"title="+clientid,
        success:function(data){
             $("#result").html(data);
        }
    }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

For your understanding, i added yourfile.php that you can easily understand.

**yourfile.php**

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("yourdbname");

$value  = $_POST['title'];
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * from client WHERE id=$value");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $result['clientdata'] ;
```

That's it.

I think it should help you.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer but it showing error <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>/data/data/www/fms/docs/clientnetworkpricelist/yourfile.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />

Comment: I think you are doing same mistake, remove your window.location and use my given code, make another file which takes your client data on behalf of your client id, and then echo it on your desired position.

Comment: Supplied argument is not valid mean you are giving something wrong in query where clause that is why it do not get any result and showing warning. you should debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistake you have done in your code. First, you set a ID for multiple element in your  while loop. Please remove ID attr from all option tag and keep the attr for only select tag as following:

```
<select name="client" id="client" style="margin:-24px 0 0 1px;background-color:#E8E8E8;width:104px;position: absolute;"> 
   <option value="">Select Client</option> 
   <option value="1">value 1</option> 
   <option value="2">value 2</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Second, you used the `clientid` variable in your script but did not collect value. Set value for `clientid` as following:

```
var clientid = $('#client').find(':selected').attr('value');
```

now please check, it should work now. thanks